# puTTY - kill SAS script running

Tags: putty

I would like to kill a sas script running in puTTY. I have multiple scripts running and don't want to kill all of them.

How would I kill, for example, "nohup sasbatch.sh panel_data.sas &"

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: See [How to terminate a background process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/104821/119732).

Answer (score 0):

`pkill` allows you to kill processes by their name. For example:

```
pkill sasbatch.sh
```

will kill all processes named `sasbatch.sh`

A more reliable method (which might have some collateral damage) is:

```
pkill -f sasbatch.sh
```

Which will kill all processes with `sasbatch.sh` in their command line. An example of collateral damage might be a `vi sasbatch.sh`, which also has `sasbatch.sh` in the command line.

Comment: Note *"I have multiple scripts running and don't want to kill all of them."*